# "Assignments are not expressions" error in Kotlin/Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm getting a `Assignments are not expressions, and only expressions are allowed in this context` error on the following code:

```
private fun blankFields() {
    blank_fields_error.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    Handler().postDelayed(blank_fields_error.visibility = View.INVISIBLE, 5000)
}
```

If I wrap the first parameter of `postDelayed()` in `{}` then it works fine - but I'm trying to understand why the `{}` are needed.

[postDelayed() docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20long))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`postDelayed()` takes a `Runnable` as its first parameter. `blank_fields_error.visibility = View.INVISIBLE` is not a `Runnable`. It is an assignment statement.

Since `Runnable` is an interface defined in Java, and it has a single method, you can pass a Kotlin lambda expression as the first parameter, and the Kotlin compiler will convert that into a `Runnable` for you (see ["SAM Conversions" in the Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions)).

So, while `blank_fields_error.visibility = View.INVISIBLE` is an assignment, `{blank_fields_error.visibility = View.INVISIBLE}` is a lambda expression that happens to perform an assignment. You can pass the lambda expression to `postDelayed()`.

---

For places where in Java you might use anonymous inner classes, where the interface or class being extended has more than one method, in Kotlin you can create an anonymous object:

```
someField.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
  fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {
    TODO()
  }

  fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
    TODO()
  }

  fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
    TODO()
  }
})
```

Comment: If `Runnable` had more than 1 method, what would the first parameter of `postDelayed()` look like?

Comment: @Zorgan: That was a little complex to put in a comment, so I added it to the answer.